# Blazor <NavLink> style stops working when included as component

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

To reproduce this issue, I created a MenuItemComponent

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

and then included the component to the NavMenu file

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Porcellus</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <MenuItemComponent></MenuItemComponent>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

And then the output is
[image]

I don't think this issue exists in asp.net core 3.1

It seems that if I wrap contents into a component the css styles will stop working.

But when I upgraded to .net 5 this issue starts showing destroying the templates I made earlier

What is the cause of this and is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a duplicate route to `/fetchdata` which will stop the second link working. Try removing the old `/fetchdata` navlink from the `<NavMenu>`

Comment: The link works. The issue is with the styling. I still tried removing the link and it's the same result.

Comment: Any idea how to make NavLink work on linux, all I'm getting is 404

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a result of css isolation. If you want you NavLink component to have the same look you have to create a .css file with the same name as the component with the styles for the navlink in it. The styles can be found in the current NavMenu.razor.css. Alternately if you want the styles from there to work on sub components you have to use the [::deep combinator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#child-component-support).

`MenuItemComponent.razor.css` (This was cut & pasted from `NavMenu.razor.css`)

```
.oi {
  width: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  top: -2px; }

.nav-item {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem; }

.nav-item:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 1rem; }

.nav-item:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 1rem; }

.nav-item ::deep a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 3rem; }

.nav-item ::deep a.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: white; }

.nav-item ::deep a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white; }
```

The alternative solution is to modify `NavMenu.razor.css` and not use the above css.

```
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.top-row {
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

::deep .oi {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    top: -2px;
}

::deep .nav-item {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

::deep .nav-item:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 1rem;
}

::deep .nav-item:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

::deep .nav-item a {
    color: #d7d7d7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
}

::deep .nav-item a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color: white;
}

::deep .nav-item a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse {
        /* Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens */
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. From the doc it seems that I need to be including the ::deep combination in the NavMenu.razor.css and not the MenuItemComponent.razor.css. When I checked, the ::deep combinators are already there, but yellow warning shows, stating that those ::deep combinators are not recognized.

Comment: The warning displayed is "(CSS 4.0): "::deep" is not a valid pseudo element."

Comment: @Wlbjtsthy ::deep is required for subcomponents. The use of ::deep you are seeing in my code was copied and pasted from the NavMenu.razor.css. I will add the required changes for the css to work from NavMenu.razor.css without the use of MenuItemComponent.razor.css for you.